# i try to grab 2 numbers or 1 with .substring but when i use the var price read only one why?

Tags: javascript

i try a javascript project on Adobe DC program, i use this

```
var t1 = this.getField("Text1").value.substring(80,82)
var t2 = this.getField("Text2").value.substring(80,82)
var t3 = this.getField("Text3").value.substring(80,82)
var t4 = this.getField("Text4").value.substring(80,82)
```

to grab for position (80,82) one number if 82 is vacuum or 2 numbers if 80 and 82 has number value... and zero if it is other character e.g.: abcd..!#...

then i use this to check if this numbers is sort and return true or false

```
    var points = [t1, t2, t3, t4];

    function is_sorted(points) {
    var len = points.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(points[i] > points[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; }
```

if i put this values return false :

false 2,9,39,44
false 1,2,9,39
false 1,9,22,39

if i put this values return true :

true 1,2,3,4
true 11,22,33,44
true 1,21,3,4
true 11,2,3,4
true 1,2,33,4

i think the program reads only the first value on position 80 and check if sort, why not read the 2 values? Is the problem the .substring command? When i check the code on [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/?js,console) then work ok! Any solution please?

Answer (score 3):

`points` contains strings and strings are compared lexigraphically (compare first char, if equal go on)

```
"32" < "4" // true
```

You probably want to compare numbers:

```
if(+points[i] > +points[i+1])
```